# WPF Seperate flow document xaml file set resource

Tags: wpf

Hi I'm trying to make a report in WPF by using flow document. What I want to do is display the date at the top like this "From  to ". I have a window that will display this report. Here's the code

```
    <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="InventorySystem.InventoryReport"
        x:Name="Window"
        Title="InventoryReport"
        Width="640" Height="480" Activated="winActivated">

        <Grid>
            <DocumentViewer Name="InventoryViewer"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

As you can see the flow document is in another xaml file. Heres the code for the flow document

```
    <FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:src="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                  xmlns:xrd="clr-   
                  namespace:CodeReason.Reports.Document;assembly=CodeReason.Reports" 
                  PageHeight="29.7cm" PageWidth="21cm" ColumnWidth="21cm">
        <FlowDocument.Resources>
            <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="date" ObjectType="{x:Type    
                    src:DateTime}"/>
        </FlowDocument.Resources>
            <Paragraph>
            From <Date> to <Date>
            </Paragraph>
             ...Table...

    </FlowDocument>
```

What i want to do is display a date, being displayed by 2 datepickers in another window aside from this window displaying the report.

Thank you. any information will be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<Paragraph>From <xrd:InlineDocumentValue FontWeight="Bold" PropertyName="StartDate" /> to <xrd:InlineDocumentValue FontWeight="Bold" PropertyName="EndDate" /></Paragraph>
```

Greetings

Rene